# insert into with 2 joins?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 1 table `auction_activity_notifications` where need to insert id  from `users` table and the column `item_watch` , also need join `email_templates` table and also need insert into `auction_activity_notifications`

I make this query where is inserting ID of user and item_watch column , i need join `email_templates` and insert id from `email_templates` into `auction_activity_notifications`

```
INSERT INTO auction_activity_notifications (id_user, id_target)
SELECT id, item_watch 
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN auction_activity_notifications AS aa 

ON u.id = aa.id_user    
AND
u.item_watch=aa.id_target
```

i have these columns in `auction_activity_notifications`

and in the end i need insert current date  into created_date_time

`id_email_templates,  id_user , id_target , created_date_time`

Answer (score 1):

Add one more join in your query

```
INSERT INTO auction_activity_notifications (id_email_templates,id_user, id_target,created_date_time)
SELECT et.id,u.id, u.item_watch ,NOW()
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN auction_activity_notifications AS aa 
ON u.id = aa.id_user    
LEFT JOIN email_templates et ON (aa.id_email_templates=et.id)
AND
u.item_watch=aa.id_target
```

Note use the table aliases with column names when the columns are same in joined tables so it protects the ambiguous condition for the columns

For current datetime you can use the `datatype` as `timestamp` and  set your table column default value by setting `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and remove the `NOW()` from select and `created_date_time` from insert and it will automatically add the current timestamp when and record inserted

```
ALTER TABLE `table` CHANGE `created_date_time` `created_date_time` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Error Code: 1052
Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous

i have aleready tryet

Comment: Okay and how to insert curennt date?

Comment: Use `NOW()` function to insert current date time

Comment: no success whats the error and data type of `created_date_time` ? its good if  set to datetime

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35817/discussion-between-dianuj-and-user2610360)

Comment: im there but you are not  answering